# Find multiple matches and place all at multiple location instance

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, csv

so I have this comma delimited file that I need to import but I need to do some replacements first. A sample is as shown below;

```
item A,<u>1 a1</u> red<u>2 a2</u> etc,content,,,,,,,end
1 item A,content,content,,,,,,,end
2 item A,content,content,,,,,,,end
item B,<u>1 b1</u> yellow<u>2 b2</u> green<u>3 b3</u>etc,content,,,,,,,end
1 item B,content,content,,,,,,,end
2 item B,<u>1 2b1</u> black<u>2 2b2</u> etc,content,,,,,,,end
2 item B 1,content,content,,,,,,,end
2 item B 2,content,content,,,,,,,end
3 item B,content,content,,,,,,,end
```

Each main item (eg. item A) is followed by its subitems (eg. 1 item A), which might also have sub-subitem (eg. 2 item B 1) as shown above. The objective is to perform a multiple match on the main items and place all matches at a specific location in both the main item and its subitems as shown below;

```
item A,<u>1 a1</u> red<u>2 a2</u> etc,content,,,,1 a1<br>2 a2<br>3 a3,,,end
1 item A,content,content,,,,1 a1<br>2 a2<br>3 a3,,,end
2 item A,content,content,,,,1 a1<br>2 a2<br>3 a3,,,end
item B,<u>1 b1</u> yellow<u>2 b2</u> green<u>3 b3</u>etc,content,,,,1 b1<br>2 b2<br>3 b3,,,end
1 item B,content,content,,,,1 b1<br>2 b2<br>3 b3,,,end
2 item B,<u>1 2b1</u> black<u>2 2b2</u> etc,content,,,,1 b1<br>2 b2<br>1 2b1<br>2 2b2<br>3 b3,,,end
2 item B 1,content,content,,,,1 b1<br>2 b2<br>1 2b1<br>2 2b2<br>3 b3,,,end
2 item B 2,content,content,,,,1 b1<br>2 b2<br>1 2b1<br>2 2b2<br>3 b3,,,end
3 item B,content,content,,,,1 b1<br>2 b2<br>1 2b1<br>2 2b2<br>3 b3,,,end
```

The regular expression `(?:^[^,]+,.*?<u>(\d{1,2} .+?)</u>[^,]*,)` does match, but the challenge is how to get the multiple matches and place them at the desired location in all respective major and subitems (as well as sub-subitems is available). Can anyone help with this? Thanks already.

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++. You should write a script in your favorite scripting language. Or use spreadsheet application.

Comment: Autohotkey (it part of the tags) might get the job done currently looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up tweaking the initial regular expression a bit to avoid too many backtracking. Not sure if its most efficient, but the following ahk script I came up with, got the job done (with some few practical modification)! Any optimization is welcomed as well.

```
i:=1, Textds:=[], linen:=0, mainhr:=vList1:=""
FileRead, vList1, C:\Input.txt
loop, parse, vList1, `n,`r`n
{
    linen++
    Textds[linen] := StrReplace(A_LoopField,"<u>", "¤")
    }
linen:=0
While (Textds[i])
{
    mainhr:= RegExReplace(RegExReplace(Textds[i],"[^¤]*¤(\d{1,2} .+?)</u>(?=(?:[^,]*,){8})", "$1@"),"@[^@]+$", "@")
    if (mainhr)
    {
        linen:=i, RegExMatch(Textds[i],"^([^,]+),", mainitem)
        Loop {
                    if RegExMatch(Textds[++i],"^(\d{1,2}) [^,]+,¤", subhr)
                        mainhr:= RegExReplace(mainhr,"^((?:[^@]+@){" subhr1 "})", "$1" RegExReplace(RegExReplace(Textds[i],"[^¤]*¤(\d{1,2} .+?)</u>(?=(?:[^,]*,){8})", "$1ð"),"ð[^ð]+$", "ð"))
                    RegExMatch(Textds[i],"^\d{1,2} ([^,]+),", subitem)
                    subitem1:=RegExReplace(subitem1," \d{1,2}$", "")
                } Until (subitem1!=mainitem1)
        While (linen!=i)
        {
            mainhr:=RegExReplace(RegexReplace(mainhr, "ð|@", "<br>"),"<br>$", "")
            Textds[linen] := StrReplace(Textds[linen],"¤", "<u>")
            FileAppend, % RegexReplace(Textds[linen], "(,,,[^,\r\n]*$)", mainhr "$1") "`r`n", C:\Output.txt
            linen++
            }
        }
            else
        MsgBox, % "Error at line " i
    }
MsgBox, Done
return
```